Im trying to use urllib.request.urlretrieve() to download multiple images that i'm iterating through. There are over 1000 images and it stops at 50
I'm experimenting with an app that is using selenium to scrape every minecraft blocks name and texture url.
The app loops through a csv that contains the scraped data and i'm trying to use urlretrieve to save these images as png files into a folder in my project.
The download stops at 50 downloads, i've tried looping through the csv and printing everything to see if its an issue with the csv and it will print everything to terminal without fail.
I'll post my project code below
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

URL = "https://minecraft.wiki/wiki/List_of_block_textures"

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.headless = True  # Enable headless mode
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

import urllib 
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Firefox')]

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

try:
    with open('block_data.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            print(row)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(row[1], filename=f'./block-folder/{row[0]}.png')
            

except FileNotFoundError:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(URL)

    block_database = {element.text.title(): element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[class=mw-file-element]').get_attribute("src") for element in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li[class=gallerybox]')}

    with open('block_data.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in block_database.items():
            csvwriter.writerow(row)```


Why are u not using Selenium to download the images (so you will stay within the browser's session) ?
